# Is there such substances that body can only send to storage (as fat)?

Tags: food, nutrition, fat-metabolism

I watched video with statement that there are such part of substance in potato chips which body can't use ("empty calories"), that they surely will be stored as fat.

It was here on 12:23:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jCd6vIF8Co

Is she talking nonsense ?

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_calorie). If this helps you, I might post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

An empty calorie is still a calorie.

"Empty calories" was coined to describe foods that only provide calories without significant amounts of other nutrients. The idea is that if you're eating a lot of empty calorie foods, you're eating less food with proper nutrition. The implication is that you will not be getting the vitamins, amino acids and other essential nutrients required to sustain you in a healthy manner.

If you can store it as fat, your body can use it. Where does the fat go when people lose weight? Those calories get "burned" when there aren't enough calories in your current diet to provide energy for your metabolic needs.